# Could you tell me that is that my question is not about patent?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

After my question was edited, I don't understand why it can't be reopened.

My question was not about a patent.

By the way, what's the meaning of "At least one of these tags is required - 'bug, feature-request, discussion, support"？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted an answer to your original question in the comments. I hope it helps.

Only two things having to do with patents are strictly considered as on-topic. One - requests for prior art. Those are question that follow a suggested format to mention a specific patent or publication number and request help in finding published documents that pre-date the patent application and show it as not new or as obvious.  Two - questions about how the US patent system works. I think after editing your question fits with on topic two.

The tags are to help categorize  questions since this is meta the questions should be about the site rather than the actual topic. I think the forced tag is to steer people in understanding the purpose of the meta site.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @George, You missed out the third point, "specific aspects or interpretations of a particular patent claim".. http://patents.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic